# Not found: /index.php/{page} was not found on this server error on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

[image]

Hi. I have moved a WordPress site over from one host to another and all the data appears to have moved without a problem. However the only page that loads is the homepage. All other pages result in the error pictured above, with /index.php/ as a prefix followed by the slug/permalink of the destination page that cannot be found.

I have checked my .htaccess settings and they appear fine:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The WordPress instance is currently on a /wordpress/ directory, hence the '/wordpress/' in the RewriteRule and RewriteBase and the DNS/domain will point to this location when everything is confirmed to work.

In my wp-config.php file my WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME definitions are as follows:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');
```

Is there anything in either that I should change?

Comment: Try this. In the admin dashboard,navigate to settings > permalinks and just save the permalinks settings. This will flush and renew the permalinks. Then check if problem is solved.

Comment: Hi @zipkundan - I tried this previously and again just now but it has made no difference.

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps. https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: What server environment are you using (Apache,NGINX) ?

Comment: @Jamie_D the server is on Apache / Bitnami. 

I have found that the only way the subpages are working is by changing the permalink structure to : _**example.com{/index.php/%category%/%postname%/}**_ . As this leaves an index.php in the url it is not the solution I would want to implement.